# uialertview clickedButtonAtIndex message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uialertview

I created a UIAlertView that is in ViewDidLoad, as the following:

```
    prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    prompt.title = @"تسجيل الدخول";
    prompt.message = @"\n\n\n";
    prompt.delegate = self;
    [prompt addButtonWithTitle:@"الغاء"];
    [prompt addButtonWithTitle:@"دخول"];

    userNameTxtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 50.0, 260.0, 25.0)];  
    [userNameTxtField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; 
    [userNameTxtField setPlaceholder:@"اسم المستخدم"]; 
    [prompt addSubview:userNameTxtField];

    passwordTxtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 85.0, 260.0, 25.0)];  
    [passwordTxtField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; 
    [passwordTxtField setPlaceholder:@"كلمة المرور"]; 
    [passwordTxtField setSecureTextEntry:YES]; 
    [prompt addSubview:passwordTxtField];

    [prompt show];  
    //[prompt release];

    // set cursor and show keyboard 
    [userNameTxtField becomeFirstResponder];
```

and the clickedButtonAtIndex function is as following:

```
 -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if (buttonIndex ==0) {
    NSLog(@"cancel");
}else {
    NSLog(@"will login isA");
}
}
```

but when I click any buttons, I see the output and then the app crashes and gives me the following Exception:

```
   [MaktabatyTableViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x894cfa0
```

Any help ????

Comment: How does MaktabatyTableViewController end up on screen? Eg, pushed by a nav controller, presented modally, etc.

Comment: it is an UITableViewController also it is the Tab item of TabbarController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have tried your code. your code working nicely .

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    UIAlertView *prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    prompt.title = @"تسجيل الدخول";
    prompt.message = @"\n\n\n";
    prompt.delegate = self;
    [prompt addButtonWithTitle:@"الغاء"];
    [prompt addButtonWithTitle:@"دخول"];

    UITextField *userNameTxtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 50.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
    [userNameTxtField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [userNameTxtField setPlaceholder:@"اسم المستخدم"];
    [prompt addSubview:userNameTxtField];

    UITextField *passwordTxtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 85.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
    [passwordTxtField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [passwordTxtField setPlaceholder:@"كلمة المرور"];
    [passwordTxtField setSecureTextEntry:YES];
    [prompt addSubview:passwordTxtField];

    [prompt show];
    //[prompt release];

    // set cursor and show keyboard
    [userNameTxtField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: its work nice alone, but if you consider that my class is an uitableviewController in the uitabbarcontroller, and when I press any button it gives me this Exception: MaktabatyTableViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x894cfa0

Comment: ya, i have check in UITableViewController also. it also working nice. do one thing, you have declared TextField & AlertView in header file. just remove that & declare as shown above post.

Comment: I did as you say, still give me the same Exception. :(

Comment: http://dt-works.com/emy/maktabty.txt this is the class, sorry for the long code, this because it is a huge project. search for this uialertview and tell me the problem if you found it.

Comment: i have check your code but i still not find because of you have so many costume classes. so i have an error that class not found. but you any of object is added null thats why you had error. so please debug you'll get error.

Comment: I discovered the problem, it is that the class was need retain in 1 object. thanks anyway for your help.